# vb Integer to c++ to ML32 to c++ to vb UInteger

Tags: c++, vb.net, assembly, dll

I'm experimenting with changing a vb 2015 Integer into a vb 2015 UInteger via a direct bit-by-bit transfer in ML32. From vb2015, I call a vc++ 2015 function in a dll which uses the inline assembler to effect the change.

By doing this, I can take a negative Integer such as -633593090 = &HDA3C22FE = 11011010001111000010001011111110b

And change it to a UInteger = 11011010001111000010001011111110b = &HDA3C22FE = 3661374206

As opposed to something like the seemingly simple "uTest1 = CUInt(iTest1)" which throws a System.OverflowException for iTest1 negative.

I have code which works properly, but I'm interested in the possibility of a small improvement.

In vb 2015, I declare the access to the vc++ 2015 dll like this:

```
' vb Integer --> c++ signed long --> c++ unsigned long --> vb UInteger -- Works!
'   by direct copy of bits through x86 ML32
'   4 bytes = 32 bits
<DllImport("StringTest.dll", EntryPoint:="bitConvert", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling:=True, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)>
Private Shared Function bitConvertTester(ByRef varSInt As Integer, ByRef varUInt As UInteger) As Integer
    ' Must be "Shared"
    ' Must be "ByRef"
    ' Do not try varSInt As "Signed Integer" or varUInt As "Unsigned Integer" --> Syntax Error
    ' Leave the body of the function empty
End Function
```

And I use this vb 2015 code to actually call the vc++ 2015 function in the dll:

```
    ' Third Method - Partial - Works!
    Dim pCTest As Color
    Dim iTest As Integer
    Dim uTest As UInteger
    Dim returnCode As Integer
    pCTest = Color.FromArgb(&HDA, &H3C, &H22, &HFE)
    iTest = pCTest.ToArgb
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(iTest.ToString + vbCrLf)
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(Hex(iTest) + vbCrLf)

    ' vb Integer --> c++ signed long --> c++ unsigned long --> vb UInteger
    '   by direct copy of bits through x86 ML32
    '   4 bytes = 32 bits
    ' Note: Function prototype is "ByRef", but this MUST 
    '   NOT go in this test call (causes a syntax error).
    returnCode = bitConvertTester(iTest, uTest)

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(uTest.ToString + vbCrLf)
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.Write(Hex(uTest) + vbCrLf)
```

And here is the vc++ 2015 dll function itself:

```
    #define EXPORT_VB extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
    // vb Integer --> c++ signed long --> c++ unsigned long --> vb UInteger -- Works!
    //   by direct copy of bits through x86 ML32
    //   4 bytes = 32 bits
    EXPORT_VB long __cdecl bitConvert(signed long *varSInt, unsigned long *varUInt)
    {
        // Intermediate variables are required for ML32 access.
        signed long varSInt1;
        unsigned long varUInt1;
        varSInt1 = *varSInt;
        __asm
        {
            mov EAX, varSInt1
            mov varUInt1, EAX
        }
        *varUInt = varUInt1;
        return 1;                   // Success Code
    }
```

I call the vc++ 2015 dll function from vb 2015 with the variables ByRef so that the dll function can use pointers to change the vb 2015 variables as needed via *varSInt and *varUInt.

My question is: In the vc++ __asm block, is there any way for the ML32 code to access *varSInt and *varUInt directly, without going through the varSInt1 and varUInt1 intermediate variables?

BTW, the vb 2015 code uses:

```
 Imports System
 Imports System.IO
 Imports System.Text
 Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
```

And the vc++ 2015 code uses:

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include <stdexcept>
 #include <string.h>
```

(One thing I find frustrating with Microsoft documentation is the failure to include a list of the "Imports" or "#include" statements required for use of the feature the documentation is describing).

Comment: There is really no need for assembly anyway, since C can cast from signed to unsigned just fine. You can do the whole thing in vb.net too, of course. I hope you are just doing this as an exercise.

Comment: Yes, I'm a retired engineer, and this is sort of thing I'm doing for fun in my retirement. But, at least in vb (I haven't tried in vc, but I suspect it may be the same), the cast from the signed to the unsigned throws a System.OverflowException if the signed is negative.

Answer (score 0):

I realise that you said you are just doing this as an exercise, but there is a relatively easy way to get the result you want in VB (or C# for that matter).

```
Function ToUInt(value As Integer) As UInteger
    Return CUInt(If(value < 0, UInteger.MaxValue + value + 1, value))
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you, Blackwood. That is indeed elegant, and quite compact. But my primary goal is to improve and increase my understanding of how to write c++ and ML32 dll code for consumption by vb. In this case, for example, I may eventually want to perform other ML32 actions between loading the signed integer into EAX and then returning the (modified) unsigned integer to vb. And, in that light, I'm wondering if there's a way to avoid using the intermediate variables.